# Power sum with different ratio and increasing power value

Tags: calculus

Can somebody help to prove the formula below:

$\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{1}{k} z^k = \log{(\frac{1}{1-z})}$, if  $|z| < 1$

I am trying to find the antiderivative term of $\frac{1}{k} z^k$, but it seemed that my direction was wrong. Because find antiderivative term of $\frac{1}{k} z^k$ for $k$ is not intuitive.

Welcome to criticize my analysis. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take the derivative instead. Let $$f(z)=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1kz^k\;,$$ Then $$f\,'(z)=\sum_{k\ge 1}z^{k-1}=\sum_{k\ge 0}z^k=\frac1{1-z}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln\frac1{1-z}\right)\;.$$

Comment: Why can derivative equal imply that the original functions are equal? They still differ in a constant?

Comment: @user2262504: Yes, they can still differ by a constant. But you know what $f(0)$ is, and you can use that to say what the constant must be.